# Can I use a cookie from an already logged in browser to make a http request

Tags: c#, http, authentication, cookies, webrequest

Can I, use my Chrome Browser (for instance), login to a website (that even requires captcha), then just simply add the cookies that are created to something like a HttpWebRequest header or something similar to be able to make requests from my own application with the necessary headers and cookies etc. to be able to get the same response that my previously mentioned browser can already get?
should I make a web browser app first, then try to read the cookies from my own app and pass it to the other components of my application?
How can I use and pass around already made cookies outside of the single browser that has it?

Comment: Sure. An easy way to still cookies is to run browser through local proxy (i.e. Fiddler/FiddlerCore) and grab cookies that server sends... You probably need [edit] to narrow down your question so it can actually be answered - questions that look like asking about design of whole application usually don't fare well....

Comment: Yes, but.... lots of web frameworks will periodically re-generate new session tokens. Each app may need a way to save the current set of cookies and reload them.

Comment: thanks guys... @AlexeiLevenkov and I'll keep that in mind